# Hyperlinks in Texpad iOS app

Tags: hyperref, links, texpad

I’ve been trying to get hyperlinks to work in the Texpad iOS app using `hyperref`, but have had no luck. I’ve tried compiling this within the app:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\begin{document}
    Here is a \hyperlink{testlabel}{link} to page 3.
    \newpage This is a blank page.
    \newpage \hypertarget{testlabel}{Here} is page 3.
\end{document}
```

This gives me a PDF where the hyperlink is colored, but no actual link is produced, i.e. clicking on it does nothing. I’ve tried putting this same document into online typesetters and I get clickable links.

Answer (score 1):

According to this TexPad support page,

https://www.texpad.com/support/generic/texpadtex/texpadtex-support

they don’t support hyperref yet.

Comment: since Texpad macOS 1.8.5, Tepad iOS 1.8.0, hyperref is suppported: https://www.texpad.com/docs/tutorials/tex/typesetters/texpadtex/package-coverage