# TexpadTex hyperref bookmarks in preview.app

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, viewers

I wonder if anyone knows how to enable bookmarks in pdf viewers using TexpadTex.
When compiling a pdf with MacTex the following will work, but not with TexpadTex.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{The document}
\section{Different section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Bit confused by your Question TOC is usually in body of document so presume you mean viewer "Bookmarks" If you can see them in one viewer then they are there in the pdf. If another viewer does not show them it a viewer limitation not a failing in the tex source. TexPad is an editor/viewer and texpad tex is a subset of what the editor supports  On iOS, in the very rare cases where something is missing, you can use the Cloud typesetters for free. On macOS, you can use a traditional distribution, such as MacTeX. Either way it sounds like you need to raise this question with Valletta Ventures

Comment: My bad did you compile twice its the second pass to get the bookmarks in {report} that worked

Comment: @KJO with TexpadTex?

Comment: I don't have texpad its down to some editor algorithms if it does two pass on first request or in my case had to ask TeXworks twice (hence my confusion that it worked second time after a change that was not the cause)

Comment: Texpad iOS apparently show them in "outline" https://www.texpad.com/ios#&gid=2&pid=2

Comment: Hyperref is listed as limited see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437698/170109 and still a work in progress from Texpad iOS 1.8.0 onwards It was certainly not working a year ago and its not mentioned in the current iOS  guide